# Refresh Backbone before a freeze

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, backbone.js, cordova

I'm using a script in Backbone in a Cordova app (Android) that freezes the app during 5s, anyway I can't do a different way.

So I'd like to put a loading message before the script runs, but the view isn't updating.

Can I wait for the update of the view to run the script with an event ?

Here is the code :

```
touchable.get("canvas").$el.parent().hide(); // A canvas to be hidden, but still on screen
this.$el.show(); // The view to replace canvas elem, didn't show up on screen
this.model.draw_full_image(); // Freezing
```

**EDIT**

The loading view :

```
var SavingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.saving',
    show: function() {
        touchable.get("canvas").$el.parent().hide();
        this.$el.show();
        this.model.draw_full_image(); // Long script
    },
    hide: function() {
        // Show the canvas again, after freeze
    }
});
```

The canvas view :

```
var Canvas = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "canvas",
    initialize: function() {
        this.ctx = this.$el[0].getContext("2d");
    },
    render: function() {
        $(".canvas").append(this.$el);
        this.el.width = screen_size.w;
        this.el.height = screen_size.h - this.$el.offset().top;
    },
    clear: function() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.el.width, this.el.height);
    },
    draw_full_image: function(e) {
        //  Long process here
    },
    // Saving image (part of process)
    save: function(canvas_model) {
        window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
            function(msg){
                saving.hide();
                window.plugins.toast.show("La photo a bien été enregistrée !", "long", "bottom");
            },
            function(err){
                saving.hide();
                window.plugins.toast.show("Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'enregistrement, veuillez réessayer.", "long", "bottom");
            },
            canvas_model
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
this.$el.append('Your message !');
```

Comment: I can't do this because my view is hidden (and I'd like to show it). I have a canvas, and I want to hide it to display a message. But I don't want to remove any element :/. See the new code

Comment: is `touchable.get("canvas")` another view ?

Comment: Yes, it's a canvas view in a div that I want to hide.

Comment: Can you update your question with the two views code ?

Comment: Have you tried my solution without the `.empty()` ? can you add you html code or only the `.saving` tag ? And last, what's the `touchable` object ?

Comment: I don't think it will answer the problem because there is a canvas before my text. .saving is a div containing a P tag with my text. touchable is a model which allow me to access the canvas and hide his parent. I want to hide this parent container and display .saving but .canvas stay displayed !